# How to update Google App Engine to Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My current Python version in GAE when running `python3 --version` is `3.7.3`, I want to upgrade it to `3.8` for a single service on GAE, I tried changing runtime in `service.yaml` to `runtime: python38` but the version stays the same at `3.7.3`

when trying to run `sudo apt install python3.8`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8'
```

yaml file

```
runtime: python38
entrypoint: gunicorn -w 8 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker servicename:app
instance_class: F4_1G
service: servicename
```

How can I upgrade to `3.8` for this service?

Comment: Could you add your yaml file for the service? You will have to re-deploy in order to apply the changes

Comment: I've added the yaml file above, also I've redeployed the application and still the same as ```3.7.3```

Comment: I think you might be checking the python version wrong, adding this to your `main.py` file will show you the current python version within your app: `import sys print(sys.version)`. Running `python3 --version` will show you the version of your local python installation instead.

Comment: As per this [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime#app-engine) you need to do this
```
runtime_config:
  # You can also specify 2 for Python 2.7
  python_version: 3
```

Comment: On GAE console, I'm getting some errors with a path ```File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/ ...```, which indicates that this service still uses ```python3.7``` instead of 3.8

Comment: ```runtime_config``` doesn't help, as I need a minor version of python

Comment: Could you try @bhito's suggestion? I have deployed my service using your `app.yaml` and when printing `sys.version` I could see that "3.8.6" was being used. Where are you running `python3` from? I suspect that you are just getting your shell's version, not the one deployed by GAE. I have also used `import site print(site.getsitepackages())` to get the path of the dependencies and they were all located in the `python3.8` path. Could you please provide the results of running the suggested commands from within the application in order to verify the version used by GAE's service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, when printing the version inside the file using `import sys print(sys.version)` I get `3.8.6`, also the directory now showing `/python3.8/`, thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

The Python 3.8 App Engine (Standard) runtime [launched in Nov 2019](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/updating-app-engine-with-more-new-runtimes). To access it, update your `app.yaml` to have `runtime: python38`. (Similarly, Python **3.9** [launched in Mar 2021](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/release-notes#March_11_2021); same adjustment: `runtime: python39`.)

Several other replies above show you how to check the running version which you can log, etc. Summarizing here and adding a few more so people don't have to dig into comments above:

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
>>>
>>> import sys; sys.version
'3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:10:52) \n[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]'
>>>
>>> import sys; sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor
(3, 9)
>>>
>>> import platform; platform.python_version(), platform.python_version_tuple()
('3.9.1', ('3', '9', '1'))
```